# UK Standard Visitor Visa: Shipping questions

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, shipping

I'm an Indian citizen applying for the UK Standard Visitor Visa in United States together with my wife.

Thanks to all the answers in this forum, we've submitted the application. After the submission, the page steps had a step for buying the courier service from VFS to ferry the application materials to and fro from the DMC in NY.

I was wondering -

1. Do I need to buy the courier service from VFS? I was planning to instead just go directly to UPS. Will that be an issue?
2. If I purchase shipping directly via UPS, will I not get status update emails?
3. Do I need to send two return shipping labels for me and my wife are though we're applying as a couple and sending our applications together?

Thanks!